# Creating "compound enums" in Java

Tags: java, enums

I'm trying to work out some tricky way to get my complex enum values. Let's say we've got something like this:

```
enum Country
{
    USA, UK;
}

enum Person
{
    ALICIA, BOB, CEDRICK,
    USA_ALICIA, USA_BOB, USA_CEDRICK,
    UK_ALICIA, UK_BOB, UK_CEDRICK;
}
```

I would like to have a simple and short mechanism of something like casting. If `country` is `Country.UK`, `(country)Person.BOB` should contain a value of `Person.UK_BOB`. Any ideas how to achieve that?

EDIT: new idea
I don't see any other solution, since there are different Alicias from USA and UK and they have different properties. What would you say about this?

> ```
>     enum Country
>     {
>       USA, UK;
>     }
>
>     enum Person
>     {
>       ALICIA, BOB, CEDRICK,
>       USA_ALICIA, USA_BOB, USA_CEDRICK,
>       UK_ALICIA, UK_BOB, UK_CEDRICK;
>
>       public Person from (Country country)
>       {
>           return Person.valueOf (country.toString ().toUpperCase () + "_" + this.toString ().toUpperCase ());
>       }
>     }
>
> // and the usage: Person.BOB.from(country);
> ```

Comment: Why do you need this to be an enum? Why not a combination of these two enums?

Comment: It's a part of my game. I have a class that handles textures of various behaviours for various creatures. Each behaviour type has it's own enum called 'BehaviourType'. And each creature has it's own set of such enums. Depending on what the creature is, I would like just to write '(creature)BehaviourType.IDLE'

Comment: @user3572544 I would call that a complete abuse of syntax even if you could make it work; I certainly wouldn't want to work on code with that much hidden knowledge and confusing syntax. Just be explicit. Organizing data is part of what classes were designed for. Have a class with some instance data; anything else is just trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I understand your attitude, but how to handle such a bunch of data: we have 10 creatures, each with 5 behaviours (same type). So we have 10 different behaviours of let's say "running". How to differentiate them?

Comment: This is a *terrible* use of enums :|

Comment: @user3572544 If each "running" behavior is actually different on each creature, then you really have 10 distinct behaviors that happen to be describable as "running". Associate the behavior to a type of a creature directly; you probably need a `running` instance variable on a class that describes a creature type. (Maybe the creature type class could be an `enum`, but it doesn't have to be.) That or maybe polymorphism might be helpful.

Comment: @jpmc26 Associate the behaviour to a type of a creature directly: Am I not doing it right now? I have direct enums "creature_behaviour". I do know it doesn't look very pretty, but each single enum has lots of variable data.

Comment: @user3572544 Sounds like a god-object. Break it up. Always strive for shorter, smaller, simpler pieces. I'd have to look at the code as a whole to make a concrete recommendation, but the approach you're asking about is definitely not the right one. You're not leveraging the tools that your programming language already gives you.

Comment: ok, this is a parameter of an exemplary enum: `new float[][] { { 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2 }, { .5F, .33F, .2F, .1F, .2F, .33F, .4F, .5F, .5F } }`. This is an array that contains a data of 1) the order of textures 2) display time of each frame. And each single enum contains such an information. I have no idea how to simplify it

Comment: @user3572544 As I said, I'd have to look at the code base as a whole to make specific recommendations. Regardless, it still doesn't make sense to use a *cast* to retrieve extra data. It's instance data of some kind. You probably need to design a class that holds instance data, and then store and retrieve the instance data as needed. If you have a collection of objects and you want to obtain a single object based on a couple properties, you need to search that collection somehow.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're going overboard with `enum`s here. Consider these facts: the countries of the world can and do change, and so do their properties (boundary, population, lots of things) over time. Additionally, your list of people may change over time, and it is unlikely that you would want a list of people to be *hard coded* in a real world application. So both of these kinds of data seem inappropriate for `enum`s. This is an easy trap to fall into when you're learning to program. (Well, it was for me, anyway.)

More to the point of your question, `Country` is clearly a property of a `Person`, and therefore should be an instance variable. This is true even if you ignore my advice about using `enum`s. These are two very different kinds of data. It is illogical that you could use a `Person`'s data where you could use a `Country`'s data, so it doesn't make sense to cast a `Person` into a `Country`.

So make these both classes with instance data (probably a name at minimum), and make `Person` have an instance variable of `Country`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add and override an `enum` method for each constant that gives the `enum` value for a specific country

```
public Person forCountry(Country country) {
    return SomePersonConstant;
}
```

For example, for `BOB`,

```
BOB {
    @Override
    public Person forCountry(Country country) {
        if (country == UK)
            return UK_BOB;
        return BOB; // or other default value
    }
}, ...
```